# Magento: Block unsetChild for all children?

Tags: magento, layout, block, unset

I am aware of:

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>as</name></action>
```

Is it possible to remove all children in one line? e.g:

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>*</name></action>
```

Or something similar..?

**UPDATE - ANSWER:**

```
<action method="unsetChildren"/>
```

Seems to do the trick reasonably well..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't be afraid to read the source file of the base block class.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php
public function unsetChildren()
{
    $this->_children       = array();
    $this->_sortedChildren = array();
    return $this;
}
```

Myriad answers in those methods.

Comment: @AlanStrom I did read the source and that's why I updated my question with the answer (An hour before you posted the answer) :)

Comment: The browser tabs — they stay open.